# Cannot instantiate the type JsonFactory

Tags: android, json

I am trying to verify a JWT that I am receiving from Google using `GoogleAuthUtil`.  I am trying to use the code at the bottom of [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html).  Here is my exact source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;

public class Checker {

    private final List mClientIDs;
    private final String mAudience;
    private final GoogleIdTokenVerifier mVerifier;
    private final JsonFactory mJFactory;
    private String mProblem = "Verification failed. (Time-out?)";

    public Checker(String[] clientIDs, String audience) {
        mClientIDs = Arrays.asList(clientIDs);
        mAudience = audience;
        NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        mJFactory = new JsonFactory();
        mVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier(transport, mJFactory);
    }

    public GoogleIdToken.Payload check(String tokenString) {
        GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = null;
        try {
            GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(mJFactory, tokenString);
            if (mVerifier.verify(token)) {
                GoogleIdToken.Payload tempPayload = token.getPayload();
                if (!tempPayload.getAudience().equals(mAudience))
                    mProblem = "Audience mismatch";
                else if (!mClientIDs.contains(tempPayload.getIssuee()))
                    mProblem = "Client ID mismatch";
                else
                    payload = tempPayload;
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            mProblem = "Security issue: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mProblem = "Network problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return payload;
    }

    public String problem() {
        return mProblem;
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is in this line: `mJFactory = new JsonFactory();`, where I am getting the error `Cannot instantiate the type JsonFactory`.  I'm pretty sure I'm calling the constructor properly and I have all of the libraries imported properly so I don't know why I'm getting this error.  If anyone can help me out, that would be great!  Let me know if theres any additional info that would be helpful.

EDIT:
Here's the link to [the Javadoc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay the issue was that I made a small mistake copying the code.  `JsonFactory` is an abstract class, so you need to use the subclass `GsonFactory` to provide an implementation.